# Highlight Cell with applymap doesn´t work in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, pandas-styles

I'm trying highlight some cells on pivot_table, it depend of the value of the cell. When the value is over a 1000 the background color of the cell should be blue and red in other case.

I'm defining my color function

```
def color_range(val):
    background-color = 'blue' if val > 1000 else 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % background-color
```

And then I applied this function to my `pivot_table`

```
 df.style.applymap(color_range)
 df.head()
```

This code is not working,  all cell are white. Maybe is the environment, I work in Jupyter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.style` is not an inplace operation. Hence, what you see as output is second operation's output i.e `df.head()`

---

To see the output of style, you would need to do

```
df.style.applymap(color_range)
```

However, if you want to see it on only for `df.head()` you could two ways

```
df.head().style.applymap(color_range)
```

Or, export the style, like

```
style_bg = df.style.applymap(color_range)
df.head().style.use(style_bg .export())
```